# Android AutoCompleteTextView: How to make sure the value entered is from the suggestion provided?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am looking forward to use an AutoCompleteTextView in one of my application. I am working up on! I am setting the list of Values to this view and there are more than 300 values. What I want to achieve is instead of having it in spinner and scroll to all available value and select one, I want user to enter the text and based on which the values would be filtered. I also want to ensure the entered value is from the available 300 values.

I have planned to proceed, when the user enters value in this field and when he goes to the next field I will validate the value with those 300 available values! But what I feel is its a time consuming approach.

Please help me if there is a efficient approach to achieve this?

**Updated:**

```
final AutoCompleteTextView actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.textHint);

    final String[] assets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.assets);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
               (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,assets);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
    actv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!actv.isPerformingCompletion())
            {
                boolean validator=false;
                for(String val :  assets )
                {
                    if(val.toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No matches found ",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        validator=true;
                    }
                }

                if(!validator)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No matches found ",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("No item Found!!");
                dialog.create();
                dialog.show();

                actv.setText("");
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Start with this one.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

```
    public class CountriesActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
         protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
             super.onCreate(icicle);
             setContentView(R.layout.countries);

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
             AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                     findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
             textView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }

         private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
             "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
         };
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!COUNTRIES.contains(s.toString();
textView.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
     }
```

Comment: I Have already used this. I just want to ensure whatever user inputs must be present in the list!

Answer (score -1):

Just ask Google. Quick example found [here](http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105&aaid=127).

Most examples populate the list with static values from strings.xml. Instead of populating from strings.xml, modify the adapter to append from whatever you have, perhaps an Array.

As to the second part of your question validating if the user is entering values from your list: (1) the autocomplete list will not show anything if non-list values are entered in the text box. (2) if the user enters non-list values and clicks enter key you can do the validation yourself.

```
ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quickSearch);
ed.setImeActionLabel("Search",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
ed.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
            KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                   // do your validation here
```

Comment: Thanks sphere4a . I have already did this. Just wanted to know if there is any effective way I can do the validation. My only concern was , if the list values are more in numbers say suppose 1000 , for this scenario time taken for the comparison would be too large! Please see my edit

Comment: I would also try using the validator. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.Validator.html